# How can I use egrep to output a range of numbers?

Tags: regex

I'm trying to output a range of numbers from a file using one command line.
The way the numbers in the file are organized is:

MMM-NNN-ZZZZ.
MMM consists of 3 digit characters representing the numeric range 375-619, inclusive.
NNN consists of 1 to 3 digit characters representing the numeric range 1-328, inclusive.
ZZZZ consists of 4 digit characters representing the numeric range from 2761-5859, inclusive.

I've been stuck with this for over an hour and what I've managed to come up with so far is:
`egrep '^[3-5][0-9]{1}|6[0-1][0-9]' l10` which gets me the first 3 numbers.

Thank you

Comment: In steps: Step 1. Do not use egrep for that. Step 2. Use awk.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The thing unfortunately with this problem is that I have to use egrep for the question.

Comment: @AlexGonzalez egrep for the question,but awk for the answer? Why such a requirement?